# fsevents-daemon vs FSEvents API

Tags: macos, cocoa, fsevents

I was checking apple Developer Documentation about FSEvents , but later in dropbox forums, i found this https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20771,

" I believe one would not use fsevents-daemon directly but would use the FSEvents API. .... "

Whats the difference between fsvents-daemon and FSEvents API. I wanted to Monitor File System changes in Mac OS , which will be the effective solution for me ? Whats the difference between fseventsd and dbfseventsd(Dropbox's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FSEvents daemon - your own Daemon reading /dev/fsevents to get File System Notifications. 
FSEvents API - Mac OS X's fseventsd process will read /dev/fsevents and gives you the File System Event Notifications.

Running your FSEvents Daemon will be best since it's from Kernel Space and will be faster than FSEvents API which is from User Space. Using FSEvents API with large number of Directory Hierarchies will be memory consuming too.